# Carbon: diff two datetime objects by dates only

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

Assuming I have the following code:

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$dateTimeObject = Carbon::parse('2017-07-20 10:16:34');
```

how do I get the `diff` between the **dates only**, ignoring the time factor?

So, if `$now` is 2017-07-27 09:11:12, and the date in the `$dateTimeObject` is 2017-07-20 -- the difference would be `7`.

I need it to make sure the results of a specific operation are being stored in the database only once per day.

Note:

I tried the `diffInDays()` method, but it returns `0` if the values are e.g. `2016-10-12 23:56:43` and `2016-10-13 02:01:53` - so, close to midnight and at night.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
$now = Carbon::now()->startOfDay();
$dateTimeObject = Carbon::parse('2017-07-20 10:16:34')->startOfDay();
```

And now use `diffInDays()`.

Comment: how to compare just date?

Comment: This IS comparing just date. startOfDay sets the time to 0:00:00

Answer (score 4):

Carbon::isSameDay method will check if the given date is in the same day as the instance. If null passed, compare to now (with the same timezone).

```
$dateTimeObject = Carbon::parse('2017-07-20 10:16:34');

$is_same = $dateTimeObject->isSameDay();
```